# Writing data to excel file from 2 tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I  have tried to_xls for exporting data but Is there any good way to export data in excel file from 2 different tables in rails. 
For example I have a user table and user details table now I want my excel file to have records of both the tables ..

Answer (score 1):

Have you  tried this

```
 `send_data book, :filename => "sample.xls", :type => "application/vnd.ms-excel"`
```

`